# SQL OrderBy clause for alphanumeric data in LINQ not sorting as expected

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, sorting, alphanumeric

I have an SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) report that is using SQL `order by` sorting and returns the following for alphanumeric string data:

```
Value: 0.0
Value: 20.96
Value: 289.64
Value: 30.99
Value: 308.655
Value: -32296.32
Value: 34.844
Value: 38.95
Value: -697.38
Value: -703.48
```

Each string has the following format:

```
`Value: numeric data`
```

The SQL `order by` seems to sort as a string but ignores the minus sign before the numeric values.

I am using C# with LINQ to sort the strings to try to match that sorting:

```
var _sorted = _unsortedValues.OrderBy(x => x.Description);
```

I get:

```
Value: -32296.32
Value: -697.38
Value: -703.48
Value: 0.0
Value: 20.96
Value: 289.64
Value: 30.99
Value: 308.655
Value: 34.844
Value: 38.95
```

LINQ by default sorts the stings with all the minus values first ascending, followed by zero and then positive values

Any ideas on how to get the desired sorting to replicate SSRS sorting?

**NOTE**

I have other types of string in this report column that are sorted correctly.
e.g.

```
"Timestamp: data time data"
"Identifier: string data"
```

Comment: Ive just tried this in Linqpad as a list of string, and its orderd it as you are looking for. 

As I cant replicate your issue, I need more information please.  how is the Description being filled and can you show more code to show how that's being populated and the class that its in.

Comment: give us more code. Your code should work based on data you gave us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose by LINQ here you mean regular LINQ to objects, not Entity Framework or LINQ to sql. How strings are sorted depends on comparer used, and you can pass whichever comparer you like to the `OrderBy` statement. So for example to get the sorting you want, you may do this:

```
var sorted = _unsortedValues.OrderBy(x => x.Description, StringComparer.InvariantCulture).ToArray();
```

Which will return the same order as your SQL statement.

At the same time if you will use another comparer, like this:

```
var sorted = _unsortedValues.OrderBy(x => x.Description, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToArray();
```

You will get the order like in your question (negative numbers first).

Why you get the order you get, but other people cannot reproduce that? That's because by default, `CurrentCulture` string comparer is used, and current culture might be different for different machines, so people get different results.

```
var sorted = _unsortedValues.OrderBy(x => x.Description, StringComparer.CurrentCulture).ToArray(); // this is what is done by default
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Evk.
I had casing problems also so I used "StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase", which solves both my casing and sorting issues.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see your strings sorted in alphabetical order. No magic here. Number `289.64` goes before `30.99`. If you want to sort by numbers inside strings, you should extract those numbers. You can use Regex, but simple `Substring` should do work here because all strings have the same prefix before number:

```
var startIndex = "Value: ".Length;
var _sorted = _unsortedValues
                .OrderBy(x => Double.Parse(x.Description.Substring(startIndex)));
```

NOTE: Consider to get rid of `Value:` prefix on the server side, because it does not provide any real data.

Comment: I suppose using default comparer (like InvariantCulture) is better.

Comment: @Evk I'm not sure if only minus sign is a problem with OP sorting. Your solution will still return `289.64` before `30.99` ignoring numeric values.

Comment: But OP does not need numeric sorting - he needs the same sorting as his SQL query returns, and this solution provides just this.